# Function for enable and disable dynamic buttons(FileSystemWatcher)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently working on my homework assignment program:) All was going well until I stuck on this problem for some time, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work. In short I need to enable (if file exists) or else disable certain dynamical button. I use FileSystemWatcher with timer for checking certain folder in witch .txt files are being created by another windows application form. So I want to enable button if certain file appears on folder , but my code doesn't work. Can some say why my code doesn't work or where the problem may hide ?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string[] stalnr = {"Stanliukas Nr.1","Staliukai Nr.2","Staliukai Nr.3","Staliukai Nr.4","Staliukai Nr.5","Staliukai Nr.6","Staliukai Nr.7","Staliukai Nr.8","Staliukai Nr.9","Staliukai Nr.10"};
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    Button[] staliukai = new Button[10];
    string dir = @"C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication6\WindowsFormsApplication6\Uzsakymai\";
    string flnm;
    string fldir;
    int StalID;
    string[] staliukas = { "StaliukasNr1.txt", "StaliukasNr2.txt", "StaliukasNr3.txt", "StaliukasNr4.txt", "StaliukasNr5.txt", "StaliukasNr6.txt", "StaliukasNr7.txt", "StaliukasNr8.txt", "StaliukasNr9.txt", "StaliukasNr10.txt" };
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            button5.Enabled = false;
            button6.Enabled = false;
            button7.Enabled = false;
            button8.Enabled = false;
            button9.Enabled = false;
            button10.Enabled = false;

        //Creating dynamical buttons 

         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {
                  flnm = staliukas[i];
                      fldir = dir + flnm;
                  staliukai[i] = new Button();
                      staliukai[i].Text = stalnr[i];
                      staliukai[i].Height = 40;
                      staliukai[i].Width = 100;
                  staliukai[i].Location = new Point(20, 50 * i + 55);
                      staliukai[i].Parent = panel1;

        // First check if there is some files in folder 

             if (!File.Exists(fldir))
              {
                   staliukai[i].Enabled = false;
              }
              else
               {
                  staliukai[i].Enabled = true;
               }

                  staliukai[i].Click += staliukai_Click;
                  staliukai[i].Tag = i;


          }
               panel1.AutoScroll = true;

             }


        /*Watcher should check for changes in certain folder for file changes and new file creation and use the function to enable button*/


              private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
             {
               timer1.Enabled = true;
               patikrinimas();
                 }
                 private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
                {
              timer1.Enabled = true;
                 patikrinimas();

                   }

            /*Function for checking if file exists*/

                 void patikrinimas()
                {
                   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                 {
                        Button temp = staliukai[i];
                       flnm = staliukas[i];
                          fldir = dir + flnm;
                       if (!File.Exists(fldir))
                         {
                          temp.Enabled = false;
                         }
                      else
                         {
                          temp.Enabled = true;
                             }

                         }

                         }
```

Comment: Where is the staliukai_Click function?

Comment: _code doesn't work'_ is not a good enough description of your problem! How does it 'not work'? Nothing happening? Wrong things happening? Does the FSWatcher ever flag any changes? Why a Timer when you have a watcher? Also: you not doing anybody a favour by chosing non-english names in your code..It is really hard to tell what is supposed to be or do what.. Also try to format the question so that no HScrollbars are needed..

Comment: Angus Chung : It's not used yet, but It has other purpose, to add information from file.  TaW: Sorry about the formation of the question I'm not used to ask for help in Forum I'll try better and change every thing to english next time. FSWatcher is added from toolbox,and directed to certain folder, timer should refresh watcher every 1s. The problem is that when I add a file in folder when program is running it doesn't enable button, It only works when the files are put in folder before I run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just modify these code then it works.

1.Add fileSystemWatcher1.Path in Form1_Load.

```
this.fileSystemWatcher1.Path = this.dir;
```

2.Set **timer1.Start()** and move **patikrinimas()** to **timer1_Tick** from fileSystemWatcher1_Changed and fileSystemWatcher1_Created.

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
    //patikrinimas();
}
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
    //patikrinimas();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    patikrinimas();
}
```

Try it again.

Comment: Thank you dude A LOT! you saved my day:) Now everything works very well:)